# Deconstruct an unknown-name value out of a function argument in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When deconstructing in JavaScript, I've only ever seen it done when you know the name of the property you're deconstructing like so:

```js
const { id, name } = props
```

But say you need a prop that you don't know the name:

```js
const namespacedItem = props[namespace]
```

How would you deconstruct `namespace` out of `props`?

Comment: If you don't know the name of the property...how would you know to ever call it?

Comment: Are there any rules you are following for the namespace? E.g. Could you use a Regex to find it? Also - are all the other prop names static? If you know the names of all the other props, the namespace is the only one you don't know?

Comment: I get an object in this code, but the prop's name is stored in a variable which is dynamically created. Instead of doing `props[namespace]`, I would like a way to deconstruct it out without deconstructing the original object using `{ ...props }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use destructuring with a computed key for the property name and the variable as the target:

```
const {[namespace]: namespacedItem} = props
```

but

```
const namespacedItem = props[namespace]
```

will be cleaner, shorter, and easier to understand.

Comment: I'm doing things with function argument deconstructions with implicit returns so the latter version is worse in my case whereas the former is a lot cleaner. My current solution is doing `({ id, name, ...props }) => props[namespace]`. This solution allows me to do `({ id, name, [namespace]: namespacedItem }) => namespacedItem` instead.

Comment: Is it also possible to dynamically name `namespacedItem` or does that have to be a static value? `const {[namespace]: [someDynamicValue]} = props`

Comment: @Sawtaytoes No, variable names cannot be dynamic. Scope resolution must be static to allow efficient execution.